# border-top-width style is not shown in a table in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I have the following CSS that should mark a specific row in a table with a thicker line:

CSS:

```
.frstdow td
{
    border-top-width: 2px;
}
```

and HTML for table rows (pseudocode):

```
<tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
<tr class='frstdow'><td><td></td></td></tr>
<tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
<tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
<tr><td><td></td></td></tr>
```

[image]

This works on most web browsers, but for some reason on one particular computer running IE 11 v.11.0.96000.18524 the table doesn't have this thick line, and instead all lines there look the same.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "border-top" not "border-top-width":

```css
table tr td{
border: 1px dotted blue;
}

.frstdow td
{
    border-top: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><td>THING</td></tr>
<tr class='frstdow'><td>THING</td></tr>
<tr><td>THING</td></tr>
<tr><td>THING</td></tr>
<tr><td>THING</td></tr>
</table>
```